# Windows phone app 8 using visual studio 2012 C#

Tags: c#

I have a login form, and when I press in the correct password for it I want it to take me to another page that I have done, how do I make this possible? I ve done this with c# in a windows phone app

Comment: Add the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms591053%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method of [NavigationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService_methods%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), something like this :

```
private void button_Login_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
  string nav = "/Pages/DestinationPage.xaml?Param1=Value1";
  this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(nav, UriKind.Relative)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the NavigationService to navigate to another page.

Check this out: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)